# Update column based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets on Google Sheets. In the first sheet I have multiple columns which are repeated, where for every 2 columns, the first one is the product name, and the second one is the quantity sold for each of the products. What I will do on this sheet is select the product that the customer bought on the dropdown, and insert the quantity bought in the next cell. I need multiple columns as some customer buy multiple product types at one time.

Then in the second sheet, I want to tabulate the quantity for each products which is predefined in the header. This is meant to be automated.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtkuz.png)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1iru.png)

Below is the link to a sample file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151D6-QE_ePOyPEeMfMO9GSOQrFVQ5AbsagOaQUm_2eU/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me with getting the qty populated on the matrix table based on the qty input next to the dropdown list? The closest that I got is using below formula, but the quantity is always based on the first dropdown qty only.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C$2 = {product!$C4,product!$E4,product!$G4,product!$I4,product!$K4})) > 0, -1*product!$D4,"")
```

I guess a good starting point would be how to get the address from Sheet1 that have the value corresponding to the table header in Sheet2.

Comment: Would you please summarise the research that you have already done. We wouldn't want to double up on that work.

Comment: I only got until the formula that I showed above and couldn't think of how to move from there. But the answer given by Metexora resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I would do it

I'd use an index with match the "Ref ID" Row and the "product" Column (offset by +1 for the value)

Then to make the results dynamic to the "Ref ID" I put an indirect range reference matching the "Ref ID". I then wrapped it in an IFERROR then 0 if it doesnt have a product within a Ref ID.

Hope this makes sense, I'm sure the example below will make more sense than me :)

Code to go in C4

```
=IFERROR(-index(Sheet1!$1:$607,match($A4,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),match(C$3,indirect("Sheet1!$"&match($A4,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)&":$"&match($A4,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),0)+1),0)
```

Example on Sheet 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eeonWF8gcvQdDrTlydmHiMzr9MZpRDAkX_fZBX95yaI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me know if this resolved t for you and mark as answered if so :)

Comment: Thanks! This really resolved my issue. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the formula though.